# Using Team Foundation Server with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control, tfs

My group is using Team Foundation Server 2010 and Eclipse.  Is there a way to integrate them?

Comment: Poor guy, my deepest regrets (TFS)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240